# Nested Dictionary check key value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, filter

I have a nested dictionary as shown below: (more than 2 keys "lots of lala's")

```
d={'lala': {'temp1': 'c', 'comp_b': 'bc', 'temp': 'b', 'comp_a': 'ac'}, 'lala1': {'temp1': 'c1', 'comp_b': 'bc1', 'temp': 'b1', 'comp_a': ''}
```

For all the parent keys in "a", I need to check if keys(comp_a and comp_b) have valid values. 
In this case, "comp_a" of "lala1" doesn't have a value. So I need my function to only return "lala" as the output.

Parent keys to check=>  `a= ['lala','lala1']`

Required values for keys=>  `compulsory= ['comp_b','comp_a']`

Here's what I have so far:

```
def check_args(a,d):
    compulsory=['comp_b','comp_a']
    valid=[]
    for a in d:
        for elements in compulsory:
            try:
                if d.get(a,{}).get(elements) !='':
                    print "Valid"
            except:
                break
        else:
            print "Can't parse details of " + a + " as mandatory data missing "
            continue
```

Question:
 How do I return the valid parent keys i.e. "lala"?
 Is there a better way to do what I've done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean way without `try` `except`

```
d={'lala': {'temp1': 'c', 'comp_b': 'bc', 'temp': 'b', 'comp_a': 'ac'}, 'lala1': {'temp1': 'c1', 'comp_b': 'bc1', 'temp': 'b1', 'comp_a': ''}}

compulsory= ['comp_b','comp_a']

ok_keys = [k for k,v in d.iteritems() if all([c in v and v[c]!='' for c in compulsory])]
ok_keys #<-- prints ['lala']
```

The logic all takes place in the list comprehension which first loops through the keys in `d`, and tests that all of the compulsory keys are within `d[k]` and that the `d[k][c]` values are not empty.

Comment: What about "a". If "lala" isn't there in "a" it should return an empty list

Comment: ok sorry I didn't understand this requirement. I believe @Willem's answer is what you need then, we both came to the same list comprehension idea but that solution only looks through the keys in `a` as you say

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly you want to check for the dictionary values whether these have, for *all* `compulsory` elements a value?

There most certainly is a more elegant way to do this: you can use *list comprehension*:

```
e = {}
[key for key in a if all(d.get(key,e).get(c) for c in compulsory)]
```

The `all(d.get(key,e).get(c) for c in compulsory)` is crucial here since it is a *filter condition*. The `all(..)` will thus start enumerating over the `compulsory` list and for each element `c`, it will fetch that element and see if its *truthiness* is `True`. The empty string has a truthiness of `False`, so that won't work. If the key is not in the dictionary, then `.get(c)` will return `None` which has a truthiness of `False` as well.